# Methods to debug python code?

Tags: python, debugging

Sorry if this is a duplicate--I couldn't find anything satisfactory answers.

I'm relatively new to Python programming, but am now getting to a point where my usual method of debugging is becoming obviously flawed. Essentially what I usually do is strategically place 'print' statements at different parts of my code, look at the output, and figure out what is going wrong.

There has to be a better way to do this. I'm hoping those that have more experience than me could point me towards some good resources. What do you like using? What are the advantages/disadvantages of different approaches?

Thanks as always

Comment: **[`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)**, the debugger in the standard library, is a good option.

Comment: Well designed code should (imho) be easily diagnosed with just a couple of prints, so consider working on Your design. For starters I'd recommend reading about object oriented programming, design driven development and things like that

Comment: To expand on Jim's comment - you can use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` whereever you would like to catch some strange behaviour.

Comment: Great suggestions everyone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should use pdb, Only thing you need to do is to place:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

in the section you want to debug and run the script, then the program will stop in the line you located it, then you can check variables, assign new values, execute next line, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any IDE for you program to debug. **Pycharm** is the well known IDE for python. There are many more you can find from [the following link](http://pedrokroger.net/choosing-best-python-ide/).

Open your project using Pycharm, it should detect your environment's python, then right click the file and try Debug file.py. Then you can put breakpoints in the code and step line by line just as you would in any debugger environment.